# Botframework Directline Message wont reach to Bot

Tags: c#, bots, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am trying to send a message to my Bot via directline v3 using C# on UWP

```
await Client.Conversations.PostActivityAsync(conversation.ConversationId, userMesage);
```

but on my Bot connector I get this message on the Directline Channel :

> There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code GatewayTimeout

Comment: Where is your bot hosted?  Does the web chat control on dev.botframework.com communicate with your bot correctly, or does your bot function on any other channels?

Comment: online on Azure

Comment: It appears that something is wrong within the bot code itself. Please share your bots code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, it's like I didn't set my bot credentials properly.